# Assistance in having create post button / send message buttons not be visible to users who aren't logged in

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently trying to set up the create post and send message buttons only be visible if you are a logged in user, I've tried quite a few things, but I ended up having to revert to the base code I had where the buttons do function, any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

edit ::: realized I posted the wrong snippet for rendering the new post button.

This is the code for new post button :

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { fetchPosts, getCurrentToken } from '../api';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Post from './Post';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar'


const Posts = ({ setPosts, posts }) => {

    const [searchPosts, setSearchPosts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPosts(getCurrentToken())
        .then(({data}) => {
            setPosts(data.posts)
            setSearchPosts(data.posts)
        } )
    }, [])

    
    console.log(posts);

    const onSearchPosts = (searchTerm) => {
        setSearchPosts(posts.filter((post) => {
            const postName = post.title.toLowerCase();
            return postName.includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
        }))
    };
    
    return ( 
        <div> 
            <h1 className="Posts">Posts</h1>
            <SearchBar onSearchPosts={onSearchPosts}/>
            <Link to='/createpost'><button className="button">New Post</button></Link>
            {searchPosts.map((post, index) => <Post key={index} post={post}></Post>)}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Posts;
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all you gonna need a way to figure out if a user is logged in or not. is quite hard to figure if you all ready have that in  place from just the snippet you posted here a suggestion.

see the snippet for a start.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { fetchPosts, getCurrentToken } from '../api';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Post from './Post';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar'

const isLoggedIn => () => {
  // code that determines if the user is logged in and return true or false
}

const Posts = ({ setPosts, posts }) => {

    const [searchPosts, setSearchPosts] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchPosts(getCurrentToken())
        .then(({data}) => {
            setPosts(data.posts)
            setSearchPosts(data.posts)
        } )
    }, [])

    
    console.log(posts);

    const onSearchPosts = (searchTerm) => {
        setSearchPosts(posts.filter((post) => {
            const postName = post.title.toLowerCase();
            return postName.includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
        }))
    };
    
    return ( 
        <div> 
            <h1 className="Posts">Posts</h1>
            <SearchBar onSearchPosts={onSearchPosts}/>
            {isLoggedIn && (
              <Link to='/createpost'><button className="button">New Post</button></Link>
            )}
            {searchPosts.map((post, index) => <Post key={index} post={post}></Post>)}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Posts;
```

Comment: I do have a token/bearer in my api just running into a wall with implementing it with these snippets of code

Comment: Edited the code I posted, realized that I had posted the wrong snippet initially

Comment: edit my snippet, again i can't tell how you would determine if the user is logged in is it if has a token?